# Trying to join table on the row with a max value

Tags: mysql

I feel like I need to use a sub-query but I'm having trouble getting the query to work right

As a scenario, I have an `auction_item` that has `bids` on it, there are three bids.

I want to get just the `user` information for the highest bid on that item.

The info I have is the `item_id`, so I need to look up bids on that item id, and join the `user` table on the `user_id` of the `bid` row with the highest bid for that item.

```
SELECT user.* FROM text2bid_users AS user 
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id,MAX(bid_amt) FROM text2bid_bids 
WHERE item_id = 11479) AS bid 
ON user.user_id = bid.user_id
```

Problem is it's returning the first row from bids instead of the one with the max `bid_amt`

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Query:

```
select user.* from text2bid_users as user
where user.user_id =(select user_id from text2bid_bids
                        where item_id = 11479
                        order by bid_amt desc limit 1);
```